# Amazon Redshift date calculation Issue/Bug

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Experts can you advise why redshift is doing this wrong calculation.
If I backtrack and go to previous day before 1nov17, I should get the output as 31-oct but it is returning 30-oct. Is it a bug ??

```
select
    dateadd(month,
            -6,
            dateadd(day, -2, date('20180503'))
           ) AS "this is 1nov17",
    dateadd(month,
            -6,
            dateadd(day, -3, date('20180503'))
           ) AS "should be 31oct17"
```

The output is:

```
 this is 1nov17          should be 31oct17 
 2017-11-01 00:00:00.0   2017-10-30 00:00:00.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is behaving perfectly correctly.

This:

```
dateadd(month,
            -6,
            dateadd(day, -3, date('20180503'))
           ) AS "should be 31oct17"
```

is saying: "Give me the date which is 6 months before the date that is 3 days before 2018-05-03".

The date that is 3 days before `2018-05-03` is `2018-04-30`

The date that is 6 months before `2018-04-30` is `2017-10-30`

If, instead, you reversed the two operations:

- The date that is 6 months before `2018-05-03` is `2018-11-03`
- The date that is 3 days before `2018-11-03` is `2018-10-31` (one day later)

So, the problem is caused by some months having 30 days and other months having 31 days.

It is possible that you are wanting "**the last day of the month**". This is always difficult and confusing for us humans and is best avoided. If you really need it, then it is easiest to obtain by subtracting a day from the first day of the next month:

```
SELECT
  dt,
  (dt + '1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval)::date
FROM (SELECT ('2018-01-01'::date + '1 month'::interval * generate_series(0,11))::date as dt)
```

returns:

```
2018-01-01  2018-01-31
2018-02-01  2018-02-28
2018-03-01  2018-03-31
2018-04-01  2018-04-30
2018-05-01  2018-05-31
2018-06-01  2018-06-30
2018-07-01  2018-07-31
2018-08-01  2018-08-31
2018-09-01  2018-09-30
2018-10-01  2018-10-31
2018-11-01  2018-11-30
2018-12-01  2018-12-31
```